# Function().prototype.call() implementation

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to understand how `Function.prototype.call()` works.
I know what it does, and I can work with it, but I´m curious about how this method is implemented.

Is it possible to write a javascript-method from scratch that does exactly the same?

Comment: It's a built-in function - to the best of my knowledge there's no way to implement it in pure JS.

Comment: The JavaScript runtime has the ability to call functions in general, and part of that job is setting up the value of `this`. From that perspective there's really nothing surprising about the existence of `.call()` and `.apply()`; they pretty much have to exist anyway if the thing is going to work.

Comment: @Alnitak thank you, I was trying to find information about this for hours today, got kind of obsessed. You probably saved the rest of my day :D

Comment: @DominikGabor with JS treating functions as first class objects then as Pointy suggests it's essential that the language have an intrinsic method (no pun intended) of invoking a function object.  That method is `.call` (and `.apply`)

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/8457c6a69a5884d4baed640f4a4f72c0322c7b8e/js/src/vm/Opcodes.h

Comment: @Alnitak: Well, you could trivially implement `call` in terms of `apply`, but I guess that wouldn't help much…

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to "unwrap" variable arguments without `eval`. If it's fine with you, you can try this:

```
function myCall(fun, obj) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
    var arglist = args.map(function(_, n) { return "args[" + n + "]" }).join(',');
    obj._tmp = fun;
    return eval("obj._tmp(" + arglist + ")")
}
```

Example:

```
foo = {
    x: 123
}

bar = function(y) { return this.x + y }

console.log(myCall(bar, foo, 444))
```

Comment: In modern JS, you can copy from the `arguments` array and use apply.

Comment: So that apply is the fundamental function and call can be implemented in terms of it